# Any of the inner element is visible jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

Is there any other quick way to achieve following functionality using jQuery.

My scenario in form validation is as follows:

- If the error occurs in the form then, show the error message for the field in an `li` inside `#errorList`.
- If user makes a correction then hide the li that matches error corrected
- If the error comes (because of calculations on the page) again, then display the same error.
- And on/before submit, I need to check if any all of the error messages are hidden. if so then only submit the form.

HTML:

```
  <ul id="errorList" class="errorlist" style="display: inline-block;">
       <li style="display: none;">不正な日付です</li>
       <li class="">16 文字以内にしてください</li>
       <li style="display: none;">不正な日付です</li>
       <li style="display: none;">不正な日付です</li>
  </ul>
```

js:

```
 function has_any_visible_errors(){
    var innerHiddens = [];
    $("#errorList li").each(function(){
      if($(this).is(":not(':visible')")){
        innerHiddens.push(true);  
      }else{
        innerHiddens.push(false);   
      }
    });
    return (innerHiddens.indexOf(false) == -1)?true:false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can make use of `:visible` to find visible `li` elements and check the number of visible `li`s, if it is greater than `0` then return true.

```
function has_any_visible_errors(){  
    return $("#errorList li:visible").length > 0;
}
```